# What is path ordered product? Please explain

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, path-integral

What is [path ordered product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path-ordering)? I had heard this mentioned in my Quantum computation class but couldn't really find useful resources to understand it clearly.

Comment: In quantum computing, path order would just mean that you apply quantum gates in an ordered fashion just like you would do in quantum circuits. Then the total circuit would just be the product of these path ordered operators.

Comment: Try with the [Lecture Notes on General Relativity by
S. Carroll](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9712019), pages 66-68 of the linked arXiv document. See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_exponential

Answer (score 1):

A related concept is the so-called "time-ordered product" which is frequently used in quantum mechanics and quantum field theory. Basically, a time-ordered product of several operators means you have to put the operator corresponds to larger t to the left of the operator with to smaller t. You can check any textbook of quantum mechanics for details. Besides, the Wikipedia is also helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path-ordering

Answer (score 1):

This is used, e.g., in Keldysh approach to non-equilibrium systems (see, e.g., [Rammer and Smith](https://journals.aps.org/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.58.323) for review): the operators are ordered along a contour/path in a complex plane. This can be easily achieved by introducing a parameter that changes monotonuously along the path and ordering in respect to the values of this parameter in the same way as one usually orders in respect to the values of time (time-ordering). In practice, the path often consists of just two segments running very close along the real time axis in different directions (the Keldysh trick), so one just uses usual time-ordering on the forward segment and anti-ordering on the backward one.